# If the first nonzero derivative at $a$ is of odd order $n\ge 3$, then $a$ is a point of inflection

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

**Statement  to  Prove:**

Let  $f$ be a real valued function such that for a fixed point $a$ , $$f^k(a)=0;1\le k\le n-1;\\and\ \ f^n(a)\neq 0.$$ Then if $n$ is odd  then $a$ is a *point of inflection*.

**Given Definition :**

$\ \ \ \ $Now the definition of *point of inflection*  is given that $$f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)$$ has to change sign as $x$ moves along an interval containing $a$.

**Strategy  of  Proof :**

$\ \ \ \ $Now using **Taylor's Theorem** on the given function $f$ we see that $$f(x)-f(a)={{{(x-a)}^n}\over {n!}}f^n(c)$$  for some $c$ between $a$ and $x$.
Now $n$ being odd , as $x$ moves along the interval containing $a$ , ,${(x-a)}^n$ changes sign whatever be the  sign of $f^n(c).$ This implies that  $(f(x)-f(a))$ changes sign as $x$ traverses the interval containing $a$.

**Point of  confusion :**

Then how do I conclude from this that $f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)$  also changes  sign $?$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $f'(a)=0$, correct?

Comment: The second term of the Taylor series is $f'(a)(x-a)$. Can you do anything with that?

Comment: You seem to have added a new tag for this question (inflection). If you think this is worth a separate tag, could you write a tag wiki excerpt so that others could make use of it as well?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta : OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)=f(x)-f(a)$$  since , by the given conditions , $f'(a)=0$.

$\mathcal DONE.$

Answer (score 1):

by taylor's theorem with lagrange reminder gives you $$f(a+h) = f(a) + f'(a) h + h^n f^{(n)}(a+\theta h), \space 0 < \theta < 1.$$   use the fact that $f^{(n)}(a)\neq 0$ and continuity of $f^{(n)}$ to conclude that $f^{(n)}(a+\theta h) \neq 0.$

now for $n$ odd $h^nf^{(n)}(a + \theta h)$ changes sign as $h$ goes from negative to positive implying that the tangnet line at $(a,f(a))$ is on either side switches from below the graph $y = f(x)$ to above or the otherway around. in either case this implies $(a, f(a))$ is a point of inflection.