# Proof of the n-th derivative test for an odd n - characterization of inflection points

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let ***f*** be a real valued function defined in a neighborhood of ***a*** and *n* times differentiable at ***a***  such that $n > 1$ and
> $f′(a)=f′′(a)=f′′′(a)=....=f^{(n-1)}(a)=0$ ,  $f^{(n)}(a)≠0$.
> If n is odd, then a is an inflection point of ***f***.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543206/if-the-first-nonzero-derivative-at-a-is-of-odd-order-n-ge-3-then-a-is-a-p) was described a strategy of proof using the Lagrange form of remainder, but it can't be used here because it's not given that ***f*** is differentiable *n* times in some interval that includes ***a***.
Does the statement hold in such conditions? And what is the strategy of proof?

Comment: It is not given explicitly, but I think it might be implicitly present. We have that $f^{(n)}(a)$ is a real number, defined by the limit of the varying quantity $\frac{f^{(n-1)}(a+h)-f^{(n-1)}(a)}{h}.$

Comment: Yes, this implies we have $f^{(n-1)}$ defined in a neighborhood, but we can't claim that $f^{(n)}$ is defined there as well.

Comment: Correct. I think the strategy must be then, take the function $f^{(n-1)}(x)$ to Taylor's Theorem. Get an expression $f(a+h)-f(a)=Ch^{n-1} f^{(n-1)}(x_0)$ for some $x_0.$ Consider the cases $f^{(n)}(a)$ positive versus negative separately.